# How to deploy nopCommerce 3.5 to new server from source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have nopCommerce 3.5 source code with numerous customizations and plugins that needs to be moved to a new server.  I restored the database backup and have the source on the new server.  What other steps are needed to ensure proper deployment to the new development server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latest NopCommerce version, there is a short instructions file for publishing your code to the server here: http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Deploying.Readme.txt

I haven't personally tried that method because I've used NopCommerce up to version 3.10, which had an alternative deploying method. (see below)

For Nop 3.50 method, you'd also need to set database credentials and database name into AppData\Settings.txt file.

---

In case you will find it useful, I'll also present my usual routine when deploying a nopCommerce (<= 3.10) website is the following:

- Create a folder for NopCommerce (obviously :)
- Create an IIS website in IIS Manager with .NET v40-enabled application pool.
- Enable "32-bit application support" on the application pool (in advanced properties). *I have some plugins that rely on 32-bit DLLs. If you don't have such dependencies, you might not need to enable this option.*
- Set proper permissions on the folder I created so NopCommerce (more exactly, the IIS process for the website) can successfully read and write data. *In my IIS setup, I need to give "Modify" permissions on the folder to IUSR and IIS_IUSRS.*
- Copy the built NopCommerce to the folder.

  - Here is a batch script I used for creating an archive of necessary files (after re-building the entire solution): https://gist.github.com/dan-mirescu/c14cc72e3f8ecca988b7
  - The script also includes suggestions about what to do next. **Please check them out**.

And of course, you also need to have the database ready:

- Restore database and optionally create a SQL user which has 'owner' access to it.
- Update AppData/Settings.txt with the new database settings.

I hope this helps.