# Publishing NopCommerce

Tags: publish, nopcommerce

I have my site up and running, but because of number of changes, i decided to publish an updated version. Before doing so i have made backup of my files and databases on the host, just in case.

Now this is what i did: Publish Nop.Web used FTP, configuration is set to release and from file publish options checked Delete all existing files prior to publish, as i was publishing to the same folder wwwroot. After publish was completed NopCommerce installation appeared (btw i would like to use the same db i used before) even tho settings.txt from the project I was publishing had the correct string path. I tried 2-3 times to pass the installation with no success (error: One or more sequence... something like that), checked settings.txt on the host and it was empty (no idea why), but i just edited it with the string path.

Now installation is gone i have my site running again with all the products and user information (i assume that means string path to db is good), but my theme is reseted to default, like all my changes to it (footer links, background, logo, favicon..etc etc) only thing that stayed as it should was the nivo slider widget that has the correct pictures displaying on this 'reseted' theme.

Checked General settings for theme settings if its the correct theme selected.

Also i have noticed this, i assume with those 2-3 unsuccesful install tried i have made some changes in db

https://i.stack.imgur.com/emobn.png

Any suggestions how to sort this whole thing, before publishing i was running my site locally and it was good, i have backups of db and files(ones that i used before this publish)

I am using Nop version 3.4 and arvixe hosting. Sorry for my long post but i wanted to describe my steps and error as detailed as possible.

Thanks for reading and looking forward for your suggestions about this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried publishing features of NopCommerce version > 3.10, but you can try a more "manual" approach to make sure that files are properly updated on the server.

In short, you get files from your local machine which are needed for the built website and you upload them to your website folder on the server. You can make a backup and empty the server website folder first.

I presented that approach in this answer:
[How to deploy nopCommerce 3.5 to new server from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599326/how-to-deploy-nopcommerce-3-5-to-new-server-from-source/28652210#28652210)

You can check this batch script to see which files need to be sent to the server. The script also includes some suggestions about what else you may need to do to update the website on the server: https://gist.github.com/dan-mirescu/c14cc72e3f8ecca988b7

Answer (score 0):

For Publishing the `NopCommerce Application` website below is the step:

**Step : 1 - Publish the Nop.Web project.**

**Step : 2 - Publish the Nop.Admin project.**

Go to the publish folder where your publish created

**Step : 3 - Cut all dll from the Administration and Paste all dll to bin folder which in main bin folder for whole project**

**Step : 4 - Copy two things from your source project and in App_Data folder  Settings.txt and InstalledPlugins.txt which is not published in your publish file so paste this two files in your publish folder in App_Data.** (You need to change the connection string in Setting.txt as per your database host).

**Step : 5 - Now you need to copy whole plugins folder from your source folder** (but remember this plugins folder you need to copy from the Presentation folder not from the main source  where the solution file are there.).

**Step : 6 - Now your publish have been ready.(now you can deploy on hosting server)**